# Define a function then add properties to it?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure I understand the following code snippet (pasted from [here](https://github.com/Medycation/angular-collection-json/blob/master/dist/angular-collection-json.js)). Apparently, the author creates a function, then assign properties to it.

```
returnClient = function() {
  var client;
  client = function(href, options) { console.log('client called'); }
  client.parse = function(source, config) { console.log('client.parse called'); }
  return client;
}

//later
var client = returnClient();
//usage 1
client('localhost:9999/users');
//usage 2
client.parse({collection:{}});
```

What is the use of this? Is this a good practice? Why don't they return an object?

Comment: The code that you've posted is not correct. In your code, `returnClient` has a local variable named `client`, which is a function that returns `undefined`. `returnClient` then returns `client()`, meaning that it returns `undefined`. So in your `//later` section, you're trying to use `undefined` as a function and then as an object. (Note that the source that you link to does *not* have this problem. You introduced the issue when posting here.)

Comment: This code errors, even when defining `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5njfqkz0/))

Comment: It seems like poor practice to me. I wouldn't recommend it. Think of it as returning an object with several methods -- but one of the methods happens to be anonymous. What does an anonymous method add? It saves a few characters worth of typing. What does it subtract? *It subtracts the name of the method being called.* Methods should have descriptive names. The absence of a name is the opposite of descriptive. I think somebody realized it was doable, and thought it was cute. And it is cute. But not every cute exploitation of a language feature is good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of this?

You've demonstrated yourself in that usage example.

> Is this a good practice?

Yes, it's used quite often. It's more common with constructor functions though, where the properties are like static class attributes.

> Why don't they return an object?

They do, but they want a *callable* object.